# SharePoint 2013 - Add Library Column Showing Managed Metadata Level Values

Tags: 2013, document-library, column

I need to be able to classify all the documents in a library into a Major Category and a Minor Category where the Minor is specific, but not exclusive to the Major. It would appear that the best way to do this is using Managed Metadata. I added the Term-set to a test environment and can, with one selection classify all the documents properly.

E.G.
Accounting
_Accounting:AP
_Accounting:AR
Asset Management
_Asset Management:Fixed Assets

The property is required so I am guaranteed to get the Major Category and may get a Minor Category.

The problem is that the single column is limited to display either the full path , or just the last level set for the term and I am looking to be able to get the two categories separately. I realize that Managed Metadata may not be the answer, but the hierarchical nature of my classification suggest it most probably is.

[image: Document Library View]